# python checking time to board plane - if not in 45 minutes, then calculates how long to wait

Tags: python

Ok so I am creating a program so that the user inputs their plane departure time

if the plane departure time is within 45 minutes of current (strftime) then they can procees to board

else, they are told how long until they can make way to gate

e.g. their plane leaves at 8.00 and current time is 7.00 (they cant board yet) so it says they have to wait for 15 minutes

```
bag = 0
minute = 0
array = []
f_row = ""
f_col = ""
name = ""
x = 0

from time import strftime

def weight():
    global bag
    print("Bag checking section")
    print("")
    bag = int(input("Enter weight of your bag: "))
    if bag >= 23:
        bag += 1
        print("You need to pay £4 per extra KG")
        print("New total to pay is: £",bag * 4)
    elif bag > 0 and bag < 23:
        print("Price: free")
    else:
        print("Try again")

def exchange():
    print("Welcome to our exchange system")
    print("")
    money = float(input("How much money to exchange: £"))
    print("1 for DOLLARS")
    print("2 for RUPEE")
    choice = input("Option: ")

    if choice == "1":
        print("£",money,"exchanged to $",round((money * 1.35)))

    elif choice == "2":
        print("£",money,"exchanged to ₹",round((money * 99.40)))

def boarding():

   print("Check to see how long until you can board")
   print("")
   departure = input("Enter time of flight in 24h format: ")
   hour = departure[0]+departure[1]
   minute = departure[2]+departure[3]
   print(hour,minute)
   time = minute - 45
   print(time)

def seats():
    print("")
    print("Choose your seats")
    print(" ")
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    f_row = int(input("Enter row to sit in: "))
    f_col = int(input("Enter column number: "))
    grid = []
    print("")
    if array[f_row][f_col] != "empty":
        print("Seat taken, try again")

    elif array[f_row][f_col] == "empty":
        array[f_row][f_col] = name

def make():
    for x in range(10):
        array.append([])

        for y in range(7):
            array[x].append("empty")

def show():
    for row in range(10):
        for col in range(7):
            symbol = array[row][col]
            print(symbol, end = " ")
        print()

#main       
    
while True:
    
    print("")
    print(strftime("%H:%M%p"))         

    print("")
    print("1 to weigh bag")
    print("2 for exchange")
    print("3 for time until you can get on plane")
    print("4 for choosing seat")
    print("5 to exit program")
    print("")
    choice = input("Option: ")
    print("")

    if choice == "1":
        weight()

    elif choice == "4":
        
        make()
        show()
        seats()
        make()
        show()
        
    elif choice == "5":
        break

    elif choice == "2":
        exchange()

    elif choice == "3":
        strftime("%H:%M%p")               
        print("")
        boarding()

    else:
        print("Try again")
```

please note I have just started python and will not understand lots of complex code
if possible can it be reallt basic how to do this? thanks

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, and why it is not working (like error messages).  It looks like you have a good start there.   This is not a complex problem.

Comment: @Fil, great! Now you can edit your question and put the code there, it's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Putting code in a comment doesn't work.  Can't you edit your original question with properly formatted code?

Comment: The code you posted will not run.  Please edit it until it actually runs, then ask for help.  I see indentation problem, variable problems, problem in your print statement, and no comparison of "current" time to "flight departure" time in your code.

Comment: @ViktoriyaMalyasova I have attached the full code! If that helps?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: @ppwater for the procedure 'boarding'...if the plane departure time is within 45 minutes of current (strftime) then they can proceed to board
else, they are told how long until they can make way to gate e.g. their plane leaves at 8.00 and current time is 7.00 (they cant board yet) so it says they have to wait for 15 minutes

Comment: Okay, so you only needs to work on `def boarding():`?

Comment: @ppwater yes thats right.